# I get a parse error when opening flutter project

Tags: android, performance, flutter, build, flutter-dependencies

```
Load Settings
                Cannot load settings from file 'E:\WAD\app\app\.idea\app.iml': ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
                Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
                Please correct the file content
```

I get this error when I try to open my flutter android studio project.Is there any way I could solve this?

Comment: Please delete .idea folder and reopen

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart